# outlook 2013 - 0x800CCC13 "Cannot connect to the network"

Tags: networking, email, microsoft-outlook-2013

I administer a small office who have their own domain and email accounts. 
for the past 1 week I have had problems with sending emails from a single account and from a single pc.

The error I get in microsoft's outlook 2013 is `0x800CCC13 "Cannot connect to the network"`.

After searching for a bit, people suggested that I should recreate the profile. I have tried doing that, but the problem came back to haunt be 2 days later.

To verify that the problem is not on the email server's end, I recreated the specific account in another computer and I can send and receive emails normally from that one.

So it must be something wrong within the specific computer / user account.

Do you know anything else I should try in order to fix this ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: (First off, which profile?  The user profile, or the Outlook profile?... though, either way...) If you recreated the profile, and the problem came back it seems to point at a problem with the operating system.  Is re-imaging the machine an option?  That's probably going to be the quickest, least painful way to fix this problem.

Comment: Are you running outlook 2013 against exchange 2010?  Do you have an attiional POP or IMAP acoount in the same outlook profile?  Check out and see if this KB aricle from MS describes your situation. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2397593

Comment: @GKoe hi there. My situation is similar, yes, but I don't connect to an exchange server. In fact to manage the email accounts I connect to a cpanel interface so I presume the email server is running on linux - probably sendmail , too.

Comment: @HopelessN00b I was referring to the outlook profile, which I add in `control panel -> mail (outlook 2013)`. Re-imaging is not an option unfortunately. The funny thing is that in several other office installations I have not had this problem occuring.

Comment: Since it worked on another computer, have you tried a repair install of Outlook of the computer that isn't working?

Comment: @CharlieRB should I do an office repair ? or otherwise how do I repair outlook only? is there a  command line solution you had in mind? Because there is no individual repair feature for outlook. only the whole of office can be repaired.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear about that. Do the Office Repair.

Comment: @CharlieRB nope.... this did not solve the problem

Comment: @nass, have you checked connection status ?

Answer (score 3):

If an Office repair doesn't help, and configuring/disabling Windows Firewall doesn't help, this problem can be due to a corrupted Windows file.

To check for corrupted Windows files, use the [Windows System File Checker](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/929833) by entering the following at an admin command prompt:

```
sfc /scannnow
```

This fixed the problem for me, and Outlook was able to send messages once again from that machine.

```
Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files and successfully repaired
them.
```

Note: even if you've used SFC before, do refer to the link as it includes some useful additional info about the SFC log, and actions you can take if SFC says it found a corrupted file but couldn't fix it.

Comment: Absolutely true! Windows X - Office 365 here. Thanks!

Comment: +1 - `sfc /scannnow` fixed the problem for me (Outlook 2015, Windows 10 Pro upgraded from 8.1, Gmail POP/SMTP account).

Comment: Worked for me, Outlook 2010 on Windows 10 Pro (clean install).

Answer (score 1):

Run `scanpst.exe` on both failing email accounts `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\SCANPST.EXE`  (or similar depending on version)

Answer (score 0):

I have had months without being able to send from my laptop.  Thank goodness for iPad.  Finally found a solution - the **Windows Firewall** had a rule for Receiving mail but no mention of mail in the outgoing section.  Just added a rule for Outgoing Mail (Outlook.exe) and I can send again.  It was a long process but we finally won.

Comment: I will try what you propose and get back to you.